# How to install software using puppet

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I have a virtual box running on my pc which I installed using vagrant. My virtual box has puppet installed. Now I want to install firefox on my pc not in my vm. I know, to install firefox I can just do `sudo apt-get install firefox` on my pc but I want to run this command from my vm using puppet. How can I do that? or can I do something like (code below is just an idea if something like this is possible?)

```
package { 'firefox':
 ensure   => 'present',
 provider => '....',
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking if Puppet running inside the vagrant VM can install packages on the host PC? Long answer: no Puppet runs in the context of the OS it's installed in.

Technically Puppet runnin in the VM could manipulate the PC's filesystem with a vagrant folder link, but it's a very bad idea.

If you wanted to install Firefox on your PC with Puppet, you could use something like puppet and chocolatey:

```
package {'firefox':
  ensure => 'present',
  provider => 'chocolatey',
}
```

See links for more details:

- https://chocolatey.org/packages/Firefox
- https://forge.puppetlabs.com/chocolatey/chocolatey

Comment: Is it possible to run commands like 'sudo apt-get install firefox' from puppet? or do I always have to use this format "package {'firefox':  ensure => 'present',   provider => 'chocolatey', }"  to install any software?

Comment: It is possible to run shell commands with puppet using the exec resource (https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/type.html#exec), but then the install would not be idempotent. When you use a package resource with the apt provider, it runs `apt-get install firefox` for you, you don't need to specify the command.

Comment: Drop the provider on other platforms, unless you need to explicitly state what provider you want to use instead of the default.